# Child components redux form validations are not working in React JS

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am new to React JS application development.
I have one parent component and two child components. I used ReduxForm input controls. I wrote validations files at the child component level. My submit button is in the parent component.

If I click on the submit button without entering data in the child components, the validations are not triggered. How can I take the child components data into parent component (without Redux) to submit to server?

Comment: You need to share your code.

Comment: try Formik instead redux-form

Comment: You could potentially pass a function as props and pass parameters into that function. I'd recommend implementing some sort of state management though if you want a two-way dialogue between parent & child components. We can't really help any more beyond this though without a [mcve].